# Set value to input in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm tried insert a value to 'input' from a ng-repeat, the variable have a value, because I can print it, but is not setted to input.

This is my code

```
<div class="row seedtime-matrix-list">
  <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12" ng-repeat="row in matrix track by $index">
    <div class="col-xs-input-samples seed-cell" ng-repeat="value in row track by $index">
      <input type="number" ng-model="value">
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

you can see the code in plunker [HERE](http://plnkr.co/edit/7UBGtsExGtoqCHJkeRpz?p=preview)

How to set the variable value to input

I edit the post, because I change the versión to angularjs in plunkr

Comment: It seems to be working for me.  When I enter a number, the text to the left of the input updates to reflect what I entered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you tried to do it?

```
 <input type="number" value="{{value}}" ng-model="value" ng-blur="printInput(row,$parent.$index,$index)" ng-change="updateMatrix(value,$parent.$index,$index)" ng-focus="clearInput()" ng-class="{'spotlight': spotlight}">
```

Comment: Sorry, I mistake to import library, the version is incorrect, now you can see http://plnkr.co/edit/7UBGtsExGtoqCHJkeRpz?p=preview

Comment: I know why. The element type="number" allows only integer number! You need to change to type="text" or try to put numbers in your array